# Request for examples of VB.net code to retrieve Amazon orders via MWS API

Tags: vb.net, amazon-mws

I have been tasked to generate a VB.net application to download our Amazon orders and order items using the API.

Can anyone point me in the direction of any samples to assist. The API documentation is very thorough but thought it would save time if I could look at some existing code.

Any offers would be gratefully received.

Comment: Is this for MWS, or AWS?

Comment: Sorry. It is for MWS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A great resource for API support is the MWS forums located [here](https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=35&start=0). Not much VB code has been posted there, but there are some users who are versed in it.

You may also want to check out the code converter [at telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/) as other MWS users have had success with it. With the converter you'll be able to take the sample applications provided in C# and convert it to VB.net.

Comment: No problem, if you find that my answer has resolved your issue, please consider marking this answer as accepted. And welcome to Stack Overflow :-)